# kitex "could not import echoTest/kitex_gen/echo"

Tags: go, import, protocol-buffers, grpc, rpc

when I use kitex to start an examples, I Got an error like below

[image]

for my step:

1. mkdir -p Protobuf-test
2. new file whose name is "echo.proto" and content is like this

   ```
   syntax = "proto3";

   option go_package = "echo";

   package echo;

   message Request {
     string msg = 1;
   }

   message Response {
     string msg = 1;
   }

   service EchoService {
     rpc ClientSideStreaming(stream Request) returns (Response){} // 客户端streaming
     rpc ServerSideStreaming(Request) returns (stream Response){} // 服务端streaming
     rpc BidiSideStreaming(stream Request) returns (stream Response){} //双向流
   }
   ```
3. open a terminal executed a command

   ```
   kitex -type protobuf  -module echoTest -service echoTest echo.proto
   ```

   please give me some advise, thanks very mush

I take a comparison to using "thrift", it is ok, in the directory "xx/kitex_gen/echo", there has a file named echo.go, but not when using protobuf as model

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `echo "kitex_gen/echo"` instead? because it look like there is no echoTest in the path.

Comment: echoTest is the module name

Comment: thanks, I found the crux of the problem, it  probably because the peoject out of  the GOPATH, so vscode can't find self module